# AWS Developer Portal - TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: aws-api-gateway, portal

I'm using the Developer Portal serverless application on AWS.  It talks to the AWS API Gateway and allows you to send requests to a published API based on info from the GW.  When I try to make calls, I get this error:

TypeError: Failed to fetch

Does anyone know where this comes from and how to troubleshoot Developer Portal?

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process worked for me while using the serverless framework.

To be able to access your API resources from the API developer portal, I recommend that you manually add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://YOUR_DEVELOPER_PORTAL_URL' to your response headers in your Lambda endpoints as shown in the code snippet below:

```js
    'use strict';

    exports.handler = function(event, context) {

        var responseCode = 200;

        var response = {
            statusCode: responseCode,
            headers: {
                "x-custom-header" : "your custom header value",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://YOUR_DEVELOPER_PORTAL_URL",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(event)
        };

        context.succeed(response);
    };
```

You can also checkout [How to CORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) for more help.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted response is the core issue. I did that but the problem persisted. What helped me diagnose and solve the issue was to make the error pages (4xx and 5xx) explicit by checking this in the console. I could then distinguish better what were CORS issues, and what were badly configured API key authorizations also blocking access to the API Gateway from the dev portal.